# How to open a crontab file in c++

Tags: filesystem, cron, qt, c++

I am working on a QT application which makes the usage of crontab easier with GUI. But I am facing the trouble of including the jobs in the crontab file from my application . 
So how do i open a crontab file in c++ application in order to edit it. 
Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [here](http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/crontab_8c-source.html) this function in C:

```
static int opentab(int uid, char *file, int how)
/* Open a crontab file under the given uid.  How is 'r' or 'w'.  Return
 * the result of open(2).
 */
{
       uid_t safe_uid;
       int flags, r, err;

       switch (how) {
         case 'r':       flags= O_RDONLY;                        break;
         case 'w':       flags= O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC;    break;
         default:        errno= EINVAL;                          return -1;
       }

#if __minix && !__minix_vmd
/* Standard Minix has no saved uid, so use the lousy old access(). */
       if (uid != 0) {
               if (access(file, how == 'r' ? R_OK : W_OK) < 0) return -1;
       }
#endif

       safe_uid= geteuid();
       seteuid(uid);
       r= open(file, flags, 0666);
       err= errno;
       seteuid(safe_uid);
       errno= err;
       return r;
}
```

Maybe this can be helpful for you.

Comment: what is the return value and what is it used for?

Comment: Return the result of open(2). See `man 2 open` in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal).

Comment: This is just opening files. How is this specific to crontabs? And this is more like C than C++

Comment: @gertvdijk I specified that this function is in C with the idea that may be useful. And you should know that any program written in C can be easily adapted to C++.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to have a look at [KDE's Task Scheduler (`kde-config-cron`)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kde-config-cron) [image: Install kde-config-cron] which allows to set up crontabs.

This is a Qt application which does already do what you're trying to achieve. It's GPL licensed code.

[image]

Comment: But isn't he MAKING an app like that?

Comment: @meteorainer Yes, so just look at the source code on how to do this is my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a C guy, and I'm still relatively new to linux, but the files are stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER` so I imagine you would just do standard file IO there.